# WooCommerce Pay4Later payment gateway return redirect is displaying "-1"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to integrate Pay4Later with WooCommerce. I have got everything working, the initial redirect goes off to pay4later, and then I have it redirecting back.

However, when redirecting back to WooCommerce, it's just displaying -1 rather than redirecting.

Here is my code:

```
public function check_pay_4_later_response()
    {
        $response = $_REQUEST;

        if(isset($response['retaileruniqueref']) && !empty($response['retaileruniqueref']))
        {

            $this->complete_order();

            return array(
                'result'   => 'success',
                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url($this->order['order'])
            );
        } else {

            die(var_dump($response));
        }
    }
```

if I var_dump() the array that is being returned, it displays the array correctly. `$this->get_return_url($this->order['order']))` displays as `www.domain.com/checkout/order-received/0`.

However, when I return the array in an attempt to redirect, it just displays `-1` on the blank page.